# Image Magick Issue: Import Error: No module named 'wand'

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I'm currently having a lot of trouble getting Wand, the python binding of Image Magick, to work. I have followed all of the installation instructions given here:

http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.3/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-windows

For the ImageMagick verison: ImageMagick-6.9.6-Q16
I have added to my variable environment the variable MAGICK_HOME with path:
"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.6-Q16"

I have done a great deal of reading on related posts in stackoverflow, and the consensus seems to be that Wand only works for versions below 7. Also, the bit size of the Python interpreter should be the same as the ImageMagick file. I have taken both of these into account. Nonetheless, I still get the following error when I type import wand into my python interpreter:

> ImportError: No module named 'Wand'

Comment: Try `import wand` (lowercase `w`) instead of `import Wand` (uppercase `W`).

Comment: Sorry, should have specified that in the post -- I did that as well and it did not work. Neither did import MAGICK_HOME

Comment: Did you actually install `Wand` via `pip` command? What is the result of `import imp` `imp.find_module('wand')`?

Comment: That definitely was part of the problem. For other people's benefit, I also realized that I was running a 64 bit version of the program in a 32 bit python interpreter. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

1. First you need to check Whether the `ImageMagick` package is
   installed or not. If not, try to install `ImageMagick` or download and
   install it using

- https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php  (or)
- https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.7/guide/install.html

2. Then install `wand` using

```
pip install wand
```

Now check in python to confirm whether it is installed or not.